# Junit Test cases for Spring MVC 4 controller to check @PathVariable parameters in @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have following controller code for which I have to write JUnit test case.

```
public class EquipmentController {

    private Map<String, Equipment> equiList = new HashMap <String,Equipment>();

    @RequestMapping("/rest/equipment/{Number}")
    public Equipment getEquipment(@PathVariable String Number){

        if(!equiList.containsKey(Number)){
            lNumber = DEFAULT;
        }
        return equiList.get(Number);

    }
}
```

I'm writing the JUnit test case for the same as below:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.ModelAndViewAssert.*;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({/* include live config here
    e.g. "file:web/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
    "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" */})
public class EquipmentControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;
    private EquipmentController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
       response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
       handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
       // Get the controller from the context here
       controller = new EquipmentController();
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetEquipment() throws Exception {
       request.getUriString()("lNumber");
       final Equipment equip = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, 
           controller);
       assertViewName(equip, "view");
    }
}
```

But am not sure if this **test class** is correct or not as I am new to JUnit.

Can anyone please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a mock of your controller and use `MockMvc` to test your methods:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.ModelAndViewAssert.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({/* include live config here
    e.g. "file:web/WEB-INF/application-context.xml",
    "file:web/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" */})
public class EquipmentControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private EquipmentController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

       this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(equipmentController).build()
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetEquipment() throws Exception {
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/equipment/{Number}", 3))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
}
```

where "3" represents value of your path variable.

Comment: Thanks @Branislav for your reply.Did you mean something like this :RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class EquipmentControllerTest {

    Before
    public void setUp() {
     EquipmentController equipmentController;

     MockMvc mockMvc;

     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(equipmentController).build();
    }

    Test
    public void testgetEquipment(){
     this.mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/equipment/{lNumber}", 3))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

Comment: Thanks a lot @Branislav. Please also let me know if RequestMapping("/rest/getInventoryBySoldToCustomer/{customerId}/{countryCode}") then test method can be like this :   Test
     public void testgetInventoryDeatilsResponse() throws Exception {
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/getInventoryBySoldToCustomer/{customerId}/{countryCode}", 3,8))
         .andExpect(status().isOk());
     }

Comment: @nish Judging by [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), yes you can. Since `get` method is taking variable number of arguments.

Comment: my class is like this:  RestController
public class InventoryController {

 Autowired
 private  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  RequestMapping("/rest/getInventoryBySoldToCustomer/{customerId}/{countryCode}")
 public Inventory getInventoryDeatilsResponse(
   PathVariable String customerId, PathVariable String countryCode) {
   Inventory inventory = initInventory();
  return inventory;
 }

 private Inventory initInventory() {
  Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
  //do something
  return inventory;}}